# Handling copy/paste and max length using contenteditable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

Is there a proper way to handle both copy/paste and max length using contenteditable in Jquery? Currently, I am using the code below only for max length. However, if a user decided to copy paste a text that is longer than the max length allowed, the text will still go through.

Basically, my goal is to set character's limit up to 200 in length, also I want a decent way to handle if a user decided to copy paste something, especially if it is longer than the max length allowed.

```
$('div').keydown(function (event) {

if($(this).text().length >= 200 && event.keyCode != 8) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `paste` Event:

```js
$('div').on('paste', function(event) {
    // handle event
});
```

Read more about it in the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event).

```js
var editable = $('div');
editable.on('paste', function(event) {
    if (editable.text().length >= 200) {
        editable.textContent = editable.text().substr(0,200); // it uses the whole content of the editable div
    }
});
```

Comment: @PhilGreene Ahh now I understand your problem, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @PhilGreene It will go through but you can always trim the content manually to limit it to 200 chars. The event used is correct.

Comment: @Anurag Srivastava I have thought about that, but which part should I trim? let's say I a user has already put 100 characters on the field and a user wants to copy/paste something that has 200 characters in the middle of the paragraph, which one should I trim? I one that is being copied and pasted or the excess characters at the end of the sentence?

Comment: Trim the entire content of your div to limit to 200

Comment: I get what you are saying, but should I allow the user to copy paste the contentFIRST and then trim the end of the sentence?

Comment: @PhilGreene Look at my solution, it trims the content after the insert happended. So its equal where the content got inserted.

Comment: @Coli basically, you would allow the user to insert the text then cut the excess characters at the end of the sentence?

Comment: @PhilGreene Yes you cannot know before pasting that a user has copied more than 200 chars, right?

Comment: @PhilGreene Yep exactly. Alternatively it might be possible to evaluate the insert position and then call `preventDefault`. But what do you want to do then?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava You can know this, but what do you want with this information?

Comment: @Coli How exactly?

Comment: I agree with you both, I just want to know the proper way to handle this. Or is it better if I allow the user to insert as much characters as he wants while showing "x characters left" or "your texts are too long" if it reaches max length?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava You can get the clipboard with `event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData`

Comment: @PhilGreene Yep like the comment boxes @ stackoverflow. I think this is the best idea, because you dont know how important the pasted information is compared to the current content of the contenteditable.